# Error installing Microsoft Exchange

Tags: windows-8.1, exchange-server

I have been trying to install Microsoft exchange for a week now. I am pretty sure I have all the prerequisites, but this error keeps popping up:

> Summary: 3 item(s). 2 succeeded, 1 failed.
>   Elapsed time: 00:01:14
>
> Configuring Prerequisites
>   Failed
>
> Error:
>   The following error was generated when "$error.Clear(); 
>             if($RoleInstallWindowsComponents)
>             {
>               # Install any Windows Roles or Features required for the Management Tools role
>               if ($RoleIsWindows8OrHigher)
>               {
>                 if($RoleADToolsNeeded)
>                 {
>                   $ADToolsNeeded = 1
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                   $ADToolsNeeded = 0
>                 }
>                 Invoke-Expression " Powershell -Command {& $RoleBinPath\InstallWindowsComponent.ps1 -ShortNameForRole AdminTools -ADToolsNeeded $ADToolsNeeded} "
>               }
>               else
>               {
>                 Install-WindowsComponent -ShortNameForRole "AdminTools" -ADToolsNeeded $RoleADToolsNeeded
>               }
>             }
>           " was run: "[11:56:49] [Error] System.Exception: The target of the specified cmdlet cannot be a Windows client-based operating system.
>      at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)".
>
> [11:56:49] [Error] System.Exception: The target of the specified cmdlet cannot be a Windows client-based operating system.
>      at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)
>   Click here for help... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms.exch.err.default(EXCHG.141).aspx?v=14.3.123.3&e=ms.exch.err.Ex88D115&l=0&cl=cp
>
> Error:
>   The following error was generated when "$error.Clear(); 
>             if($RoleInstallWindowsComponents)
>             {
>               # Install any Windows Roles or Features required for the Management Tools role
>               if ($RoleIsWindows8OrHigher)
>               {
>                 if($RoleADToolsNeeded)
>                 {
>                   $ADToolsNeeded = 1
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                   $ADToolsNeeded = 0
>                 }
>                 Invoke-Expression " Powershell -Command {& $RoleBinPath\InstallWindowsComponent.ps1 -ShortNameForRole AdminTools -ADToolsNeeded $ADToolsNeeded} "
>               }
>               else
>               {
>                 Install-WindowsComponent -ShortNameForRole "AdminTools" -ADToolsNeeded $RoleADToolsNeeded
>               }
>             }
>           " was run: "The target of the specified cmdlet cannot be a Windows client-based operating system.".
>
> The target of the specified cmdlet cannot be a Windows client-based operating system.
>   Click here for help... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms.exch.err.default(EXCHG.141).aspx?v=14.3.123.3&e=ms.exch.err.Ex88D115&l=0&cl=cp
>
> Elapsed Time: 00:00:22
>
> Management Tools Prerequisites
>   Completed
>
> Elapsed Time: 00:00:48
>
> Languages Prerequisites
>   Completed
>
> Elapsed Time: 00:00:04

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

The key is this message:

> The target of the specified cmdlet cannot be a Windows client-based operating system.

Meaning: You can't install it on Windows 8.1. It has to be installed on Windows Server.

Comment: so i should install a different setup , for windows ?